# Using matplot in R whenever certain column changes

Tags: r, plot, visualization

Sorry in advance because I am new at asking questions here and don't know how to input this table properly.

Say I have a data frame in R constructed like:

```
team = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C") 

value = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)

m = cbind(team, value)
```

I want to create a plot that will give me 3 lines graphing the values for teams `A, B, and C.` I believe I can do this inputting the matrix m into `matplot` somehow, but I'm not sure how.

EDIT: I've gotten a lot closer to solving my problem. However I've realized that for some reason, with the code I have, "Value" is a list of 745 which matches the number of rows in my dataframe m. However when I unlist(Value) it turns into a numeric of length 894. Any ideas on why this would happen?

Comment: and what have you already tried?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
team = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C")
value = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
m = cbind.data.frame(team, value)
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(m, aes(x=as.factor(1:nrow(m)), y=value, group=team, col=team)) + 
  geom_line(lwd=2) + xlab('index')
```

[image]

Comment: I got this error:

Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type list. Defaulting to continuous.
Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 26, 0

Comment: are you using the same dataset? where exactly u got the error?

Comment: No, I'm using a larger dataset but with the same type of problem. My dataset has 745 rows with ~20 different teams that I want to put on the same graph. The teams do not all have the same number of rows.

Comment: if you just want to plot by index, it does not need to have the same # rows for all teams.

Comment: Good, I didn't think so, but I still don't know why I'm getting this error

Comment: I just found out that the "Value" column in my code is of type list. I'm not sure where to go from here.

Comment: Value column should be numeric (integers), have df$Value <- unlist(df$Value)

Comment: I'm getting the error "arguments imply differing number of rows" when I try to unlist that way. However if I do Value = unlist(df$Value) that works, however I still can't use ggplot.

Answer (score 0):

if you have same number of ordered values for each team, you could use `matplot` to visualize them. but the data should be converted to matrix first;

```
m = cbind.data.frame(team, value, index = rep(1:3, 3))

m <- reshape(m, v.names = 'value', idvar = 'team', direction = 'wide', timevar = 'index')

matplot(t(m[, 2:4]), type = 'l', lty = 1)
legend('top', legend = m[, 1], lty = 1, col = 1:3)
```

Comment: I don't actually have the same number of ordered values for each team in the data I want to use